# Listening for an event to fire off a method in another class (Rx)

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

Very new to RxJava/RxAndroid, but I thought that since Rx is often used for event handling, perhaps this would be a good situation to try it out.

I have a custom view, which inside the custom views class im using a `Runnable` to handle long press clicks:

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable longPressed = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //Call method in this views Activity here.
        }
    };
```

I would then want to call a method in the Activity when this event is fired off and `run()` is called. Could calling the method in the Activity with Rx be a clean solution? How would this be done using RxJava/RxAndroid?

Answer (score 3):

You could simple create a listner interface for this.

```
public interface ViewUpdateListner{
void update();
}
```

then call this :

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable longPressed = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            updateListner.update();
        }
    };
```

set the Listner in the activity like you do for a button click.

```
view.setOnViewUpdateListner(this);
```

Now if you want to use Rx for this ,then simply you could wrap your listner around it in your Custom View class. Like

```
 public static Observable<ViewUpdateEvent> viewUpdateEvents(View view) {
    return Observable.create(new ViewUpdateEventOnSubscribe(view));
  }

    final class ViewUpdateEventOnSubscribe implements Observable.OnSubscribe<ViewUpdateEvent> {
  final View view;

  ViewUpdateEventOnSubscribe (View view) {
    this.view = view;
  }

  @Override public void call(final Subscriber<? super ViewUpdateEvent> subscriber) {
   ViewUpdateListnerlistner listner= new ViewUpdateListner() {
                @Override
                public void update() {
                    if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                        subscriber.onNext(new ViewUpdateEvent());
                    }
                }
            };
  view.setOnViewUpdateListner(listner);
  }
}
```

then you could use it in your activity like :

```
viewUpdateEvents(view)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(new Observer<ViewUpdateEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(ViewUpdateEvent update) {

        };)
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi I am also newbie on Rx, We can use RxJava to implement simple Event Bus.

So for the question we publish an event when long press is triggered, and subscribe the event on Activity. so Activity will be notified to do something if event has been emitted.

Here are what I have tried:

```
public class RxBus {

  private final Subject<Object, Object> mRxBus = new SerializedSubject<>(PublishSubject.create());

  private static RxBus mInstance;

  public static RxBus getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new RxBus();
    }
    return mInstance;
  }

  private RxBus() {

  }
  public void send(Object o) {
    mRxBus.onNext(o);
  }

  public Observable<Object> toObserverable() {
    return mRxBus;
  }

  public boolean hasObservers() {
    return mRxBus.hasObservers();
  }
}
```

On a fragment class:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = MainFragment.class.toString();
private RxBus mRxBus;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mRxBus.hasObservers()) {
            mRxBus.send(new LongPressEvent());
        }
    }
};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    Button longPressButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.longpress_button_main);
    longPressButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 3000);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mRxBus = RxBus.getInstance();
}

public static class LongPressEvent {

}
}
```

finally on Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.toString();
private static final String FRAGMENT_TAG = "fragment_tag";
private RxBus mRxBusInstance = RxBus.getInstance();

private CompositeSubscription mCompositeSubscription;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initView();
    eventSubscription();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mCompositeSubscription.unsubscribe();
}

private void eventSubscription() {
    mCompositeSubscription = new CompositeSubscription();
    getRxBusInstance();

    Observable<Object> longPressEvent = mRxBusInstance.toObserverable();
    mCompositeSubscription.add(longPressEvent.subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object o) {
            if (o instanceof MainFragment.LongPressEvent) {
                //do something here
            }
        }
    }));
}
}
```

Hope this help!! and the reference for more information from below blog

http://nerds.weddingpartyapp.com/tech/2014/12/24/implementing-an-event-bus-with-rxjava-rxbus/

Comment: That seems like an excessive amount of code for a framework thats suppose to help in exact situations like this..